How to access command line tools written with Xcode
I am writing many command line tools in C++ under Xcode. Can anyone guess the apple intended way of accessing them? They are very hidden, for example one of them is at

/Users/adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bbrwianlhezalzchgferzxgfjbwf/Build/Products/Debug

I didn't see an option for placing executables in more accessible folders.
Of course, I could execute it through Xcode, but the whole point of "command line" tool is that it can be run in a terminal.

That's hardly fair. It isn't really 8 steps; I could have just said "Archive and export". And yes, I think just about everyone does know about that, since every project requires it eventually. But you seemed not to know about that so I took the trouble to enact the whole thing in detail. I was trying to be helpful, not offensive.

Don't use the one in Products/Debug for anything; it's a debug build. You want a release build. Here's how to get one.

First, say Product > Archive. The product will build and the Organizer window will open.

Select the build you just archived.

Click Distribute Content.

Click Custom.

Click Next.

Click Built Products.

Click Next.

Pick a place to save to, and click Export.


What just happened is that you saved a folder with your CLI (deep) inside it. Now you can put wherever you like.
